# How to merge pages of a PDF document into a single page from command line?

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, thermal-printer

I have an HTML document to be printed in an 80mm paper roll. So, I convert the HTML document to PDF and use the `lp` command to print it. Problem is: the generated PDF file breaks my document into pages. What I need is to **merge PDF pages into a single page which has the height of the HTML document I am converting from**

Comment: Your question seems to lack the specific information others need to investigate and verify. Please add information such as printer vendor, model, mode setting, device driver, OS type, version, software system, programming language, library, source code of problem, and test data.

Comment: For example, this printer and mode allow for page size settings of 80mm x 3276mm. [Advanced Printer Driver 6 Printer Specification for TM-T20X](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pos/bulk/apd6_spec_t20x_en_reva.pdf), [レシート用紙サイズをカスタム作成するには（上級者向け）](https://www.feelix.jp/blog/support/2017/03/11/%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E7%94%A8%E7%B4%99%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%82%92%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%A0%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%EF%BC%88%E4%B8%8A/)